# Проблема с отправкой СМС с помощью SmsManager

Tags: android, sms

Есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую на это же устройство должно приходить смс - что-то вроде кода подтверждения регистрации. Пробовал использовать `SmsManager`.

Такую строку прописал в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Сам метод:

```
public void onSend(View v) {
    String phoneNum = "+996707157XXX"; //формат номера менять пробовал
    String smsMsg = "TA-DA";

    try {
        Toast.makeText(this, "TADA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, smsMsg, null, null); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Тестировал на реальном устройстве SGS4: Android KikKat 4.4.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: С ошибкой падает?

Comment: @АлексейМальченко нет без ошибок

Comment: Тебе нужно посмотреть с какой ошибкой вылетает исключение. В блоке catch отладься и посмотри.

Comment: А Вы на реальном устройстве тестируете? Если нет то как?

Comment: @АлексейМальченко ошибки вроде никакие не вылетают

Comment: @IvanBlack Да на реальном устройстве

Comment: в блоке catch напиши throw e; упадет?

Comment: Импорт `android.telephony.SmsManager` или `android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager`? Первый?

Comment: @АлексейМальченко ничего не происходит и в logcat ничего

Comment: @IvanBlack android.telephony.SmsManager

Comment: Есть ещё лимит отправки сообщений. Для 4.4.1 например 30 сообщений за 30 минут. Больше никак.

Comment: @АлексейМальченко, он исключение бросит только если номер или текст сообщения пусты.

Comment: Ну так не бывает. Что бы в лог не писал и исключение не вызывалось...
А ты хочешь отправить без палева, или открыть стандартное окошко отправки? Может тебе вообще менеджер юзать не надо...

Comment: @IvanBlack Да нет, лимит я вроде не исчерпал

Comment: Может оператор отмораживает. Вот попробуйте с BroadCastReciver'ом если нечего не получается. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24845193/1816872 - можно отслеживать доставку.

Comment: @АлексейМальченко нет, хотел отправить просто смс с кодом подтверждения прямо с прилолжения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
PendingIntent sentPI;
String SENT = "SMS_SENT";

sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,new Intent(SENT), 0);

sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, null);
```

Comment: попробуй так, используя намерение

Comment: не сработало, может в устройстве проблема или с оператором что-то

Comment: да не должно быть... вобщем без логов ничего не выйдет.

Comment: не.. тут нет полезной информации.